# Rename tags zerg, terran, and protoss to starcraft-zerg, starcraft-terran, and starcraft-protoss?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, ambiguous-tags

Currently there are three tags called [zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zerg) [terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terran) and [protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protoss)

I think having these current tag names is like tagging things  [redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redstone) and [minecart](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecart) instead of [minecraft-redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redstone) and [minecraft-minecart](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-minecart)

So I think that the [zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zerg) [terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terran) and [protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protoss) should be renamed to [starcraft-zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-zerg) [starcraft-terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-terran) and [starcraft-protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-protoss)

Or, at least a tag synonym.

Comment: The appropriate Meta Tag is [Tag:Discussion] *"The question you're asking is designed to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching community consensus."*

Comment: Is there actually a need to relate tags like "zerg" back to the game that they are from? What is the advantage of "starcraft-zerg" over "zerg"?

Comment: What if another game has zergs? Then what?

Comment: @JoethePerson if another game had Zerg, it would almost certainly be copying SCII. "Terran" I can see having problems with as Terran is more broadly used.

Answer (score 4):

I personally think that we should rename them to be [starcraft-zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-zerg), [starcraft-protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-protoss), and [starcraft-terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-terran). The reason being is that all other tags that have subcategories in them, such as Minecraft, TF2, and Skyrim all follow this naming convention, so we should continue this convention to be consistent.

I don't think we need to change it to use StarCraft II in the tag name, or have separate tags for StarCraft II terran, protoss, and zerg, because the the units are from the StarCraft universe and the renaming of the tag is to eliminate any ambiguity that may exist by showing explicitly that these tags are sub-categories within StarCraft.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a (new) problem with the current [zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zerg), [protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protoss) and [terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terran) tags.  These tags are being used to categorise both [starcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft) and [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) questions.

I found questions with the following combinations:

- [zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zerg)[starcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft) = 5
- [protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protoss)[starcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft) = 1
- [terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terran)[starcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft) = 0
- [zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zerg)[starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) = 116
- [protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protoss)[starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) = 85
- [terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terran)[starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) = 84

What I propose is:

- [zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zerg) becomes [starcraft-2-zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2-zerg)
- [protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protoss) becomes [starcraft-2-protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2-protoss)
- [terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terran) becomes [starcraft-2-terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2-terran)
- The questions that use either [zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zerg), [protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protoss) or [terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terran) with [starcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft) are amended to no longer use the race tags... unless there is a case for using the same tagging scheme on old Starcraft questions.

Comment: ...There seems to be no issue here.  This is exactly how these tags should be used.

Comment: @frank - Are we to assume that someone with expertise in Starcraft's Zerg is the same as having expertise in Starcraft 2's Zerg?  Also, most in not all of the classes in Team Fortress 2 are also in the original Team Fortress, but these tags are prefixed with tf2.