# Retag request for zerg, protoss, and terran

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There [seems](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2947/rename-tags-zerg-terran-and-protoss-to-starcraft-zerg-starcraft-terran-and-s) to be a general agreement that [zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zerg), [protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protoss), and [terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terran) should be retagged as [starcraft-zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-zerg), [starcraft-protoss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-protoss), and [starcraft-terran](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-terran) so that they follow the same convention as subtags for TF2, Minecraft, and Skyrim. Also the renaming of the tag will help eliminate any ambiguity that may exist by showing explicitly that these tags are sub-categories within StarCraft.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a good idea. Done.